# Join in Linq query not working

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

Now I have to sum the results by grouping the customers.

I have made a query but It is not working at all. Can anybody help me? Here is my query:

```
![var query=from p in context.Delivery
            join o in
                (from o1 in context.OrderTables select o1)
            on p.OrderID equals o.OrderID
            into go from po in go.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join d in (from d1 in context.Diagram select d1)
            on po.DiagramID equals d.DiagramID into gd
            from pd in gd.Distinct()
            group pd by pd.CustomerID into groupCustomer
                join cu in context.CustomerCompanyTables
                on groupCustomer.Key equals cu.CustomerID
           select new { cu.CompanyName, SumNoTax = p.Sum(t => t.OrderID!=0 ? p.Price:d.Price)};][2]
```

Comment: Please expand on how it is not working. Eg. given some data what are you getting vs. what do you expect to get?

Comment: @Richard, the error can be seen in the screen shot.

Comment: No, that is where the error is, not what error (lots of errors are possible). Add to the Q the text of the error.

Comment: @Richard, I m unable to get the order table and pdtdelivery table values finally.

Comment: That isn't a compiler error: cut and paste (with edits to match your quoted code) the compiler output.  (The query seems—to put it bluntly—incoherent with lots of excess: eg. why are you joining a sub-query rather than the `DbSet<…>` directly?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in the comments your query seems massively over complicated:

- The use of

  ```
  …
  join x in (from z in context.Xx select z) on …
  ```

  rather than just:

  ```
  …
  join x in context.Xx on …
  ```
- Those checks for non-exitant data (`go.DefaultIfEmpty()`): the form
  of `join` you are using is an *inner* join: data will be returned
  only when matching objects exist for both sides of the condition.

But in the end, your problem is refering back to the original collections
in the final `select` clause rather than to the result of the `group by`.

And of course there is no `SellingPrice` in `PdtDeliveryTable` also
used in that final `select` clause.

---

My approach with queries like this is to build things up incrementally,
ensuring I understand what I am doing with each step.

So the first step is to do the join. For this purpose I've defined
a slightly simpler structure to try and keep things clear (see the
bottom of this answer for definitions) and some test data. I'm using
LINQ to Objects, but the synatax and semantics of the LINQ operators
is the same (and it saves creating a more complex project & database).

A customer has multiple orders, each with a single Sku (stock control
unit—a product). The order can optionally override the default price
of the sku (hence using a `Nullable<decimal>`). There is also some
test data.

**The first step** is to check I'm doing the join right, and check
I'm handling that price override:

```
var ctx = GetTestData();

var query = from c in ctx.Customers
            join o in ctx.Orders on c.CustomerId equals o.CustomerId
            join s in ctx.Skus on o.SkuId equals s.SkuId
            select new { Customer = c, Order = o, Sku = s };

Console.WriteLine("CustId\tCust\t\tOrder\tSku\tPaid");
foreach (var v in query) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}",
                      v.Customer.CustomerId,
                      v.Customer.Name,
                      v.Order.OrderId,
                      v.Sku.SkuId,
                      v.Order.SpecificPrice ?? v.Sku.DefaultPrice);
}
```

which results in

```
CustId  Cust            Order   Sku     Paid
1       Acme Corp       1       1       10.0
1       Acme Corp       2       2       15.0
1       Acme Corp       3       3       30.0
2       Beta Corp       4       1       9.99
```

Note the only data is where there are matching objects of each type, so
there is nothing from the third customer (has no orders) and only one row
from the second customer (doesn't have any orders for other SKUs): there
are no null objects to remove.

**The second step** is to perform the grouping. This will result in
a rather different data structure something like:

```
class AnonOfGroup : IEnumerable<AnonOfRow> {
   KeyType Key;
}
```

where `AnonOfRow` is the type of whatever you are grouping.

Thus:

```
var query = from c in ctx.Customers
            join o in ctx.Orders on c.CustomerId equals o.CustomerId
            join s in ctx.Skus on o.SkuId equals s.SkuId
            select new { Customer = c, Order = o, Sku = s } into joinRes
            group joinRes by joinRes.Customer.CustomerId into g
            select g;
```

has, using the above terms the type of `Key` being the type of `CustomerId` and
`AnonOfRow` being the type of `joinRes` which is the type of the first
`select` clause.

This can be shown with a double loop:

- Outer over the each different group (with the same key)
- Inner over each object in each group (created by the first `select`
  clause)

so:

```
Console.WriteLine("Customer");
Console.WriteLine("\tOrder\tSku\tPrice");
foreach (var grp in query) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", grp.Key, grp.First().Customer.Name);
    foreach (var row in grp) {
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}\t{2}",
                          row.Order.OrderId,
                          row.Sku.SkuId,
                          row.Order.SpecificPrice ?? row.Sku.DefaultPrice);
    }
}
```

gives:

```
Customer
        Order   Sku     Price
1: Acme Corp
        1       1       10.0
        2       2       15.0
        3       3       30.0
2: Beta Corp
        4       1       9.99
```

Note also that I'm alble to access the "inner data" from the outer loop
by performing some enumeration (in this case I know the customer is
the same in each inner object so I'll use the first). This is safe
because the underlying join is an inner join.

**The Final Step** is to sum over each order within the group. This can
be done for each group in the final `select` cluase. This will be processed
*once* for each *group*, but within that clause we can aggregate
over the rows in that group:

```
var query = from c in ctx.Customers
            join o in ctx.Orders on c.CustomerId equals o.CustomerId
            join s in ctx.Skus on o.SkuId equals s.SkuId
            select new { Customer = c, Order = o, Sku = s } into joinRes
            group joinRes by joinRes.Customer.CustomerId into g
            select new {
                CustomerId = g.Key,
                CustomerName = g.First().Customer.Name,
                TotalPrice = g.Sum(r => r.Order.SpecificPrice ?? r.Sku.DefaultPrice)
            };

Console.WriteLine("Cust\tName\t\tTotal");
foreach (var row in query) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", row.CustomerId, row.CustomerName, row.TotalPrice);
}
```

In this case the aggregation changes the list of lists into a (flat)
list, so only needing a single loop to see all the data. The use of
the null check within the summation means that there are no nulls:

```
Cust    Name            Total
1       Acme Corp       55.0
2       Beta Corp       9.99
```

which is clearly correct for the input data.

**Your Solution** should just be a matter of substituting your types, adding the fourth
as an extra join, and adjusting to the slightly different types.

---

```
class Customer {
    public int CustomerId;
    public string Name;
}

class Sku {
    public int SkuId;
    public decimal DefaultPrice;
}

class Order {
    public int OrderId;
    public int CustomerId;
    public int SkuId;
    public decimal? SpecificPrice;
}

class Context {
    public List<Customer> Customers;
    public List<Sku> Skus;
    public List<Order> Orders;
}

static Context GetTestData() {
    var customers = new List<Customer> {
        new Customer { CustomerId = 1, Name = "Acme Corp" },
        new Customer { CustomerId = 2, Name = "Beta Corp" },
        new Customer { CustomerId = 3, Name = "Gamma Corp" }
    };

    var skus = new List<Sku> {
        new Sku { SkuId = 1, DefaultPrice = 10.0m },
        new Sku { SkuId = 2, DefaultPrice = 20.0m },
        new Sku { SkuId = 3, DefaultPrice = 30.0m }
    };

    var orders = new List<Order> {
        new Order { OrderId = 1, CustomerId = 1, SkuId = 1 },
        new Order { OrderId = 2, CustomerId = 1, SkuId = 2, SpecificPrice = 15.0m },
        new Order { OrderId = 3, CustomerId = 1, SkuId = 3 },
        new Order { OrderId = 4, CustomerId = 2, SkuId = 1, SpecificPrice = 9.99m }
    };

    return new Context {
        Customers = customers,
        Skus = skus,
        Orders = orders
    };
}
```